# SCSS syntax for list and map

Tags: angular, sass, scss-mixins

I'm trying to run the following code in Angular v16.

```scss
@use "sass:map";
@use "sass:list";

list.append(10px 20px, 30px); // ERROR expectedscss(css-lcurlyexpected)
@debug list.append(10px 20px, 30px);

$font-weights: ("regular": 400, "medium": 500, "bold": 700);
map.set($font-weights, "regular", 300); // ERROR expectedscss(css-lcurlyexpected)
@debug map.set($font-weights, "regular", 300);
```

When I'm using `list.append()` and `map.set()` I receive the above errors. However, if I use @debug then it works.
I'm missing something?

The error `// ERROR expectedscss(css-lcurlyexpected)` I receive it both in my editor, VSCode and in the terminal.

Also, copying this code into a new `.scss` file in VSCode will show the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because `list.append()` and `map.set()` both return a copy of the given list/map, and so expect to be assigned to a variable (when not used in `@debug`). The documentation seems a bit misleading on this, as I haven't found any mention of it and the examples don't use assignments.

```scss
@use "sass:map";
@use "sass:list";

$newList: list.append(10px 20px, 30px);

$font-weights: ("regular": 400, "medium": 500, "bold": 700);
$newMap: map.set($font-weights, "regular", 300);
```